# mp3 file can't play in android

Tags: android, mp3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUBwV.png)I'm trying to run an mp3 file on Android Studio, but I keep getting this error! The file name must end with .xml

**Any idea please!!**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EWVA.png)

Comment: In the screenshot file path app\src\res\song... Please check this file path or check mp3 file in resource folder.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
// first import MediaPlayer
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

// then onCreate
mysong = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.songame);
mysong.setLooping(true);
mysong.start();
```

simple and easy this metode work for me all time
i see that u put like this

```
mysong = MediaPlayer.create(sound.this, R.raw.songame);
```

you don't need that 'sound' in context

Comment: yes i do all this and i still have error : The file name must end with .xml

Comment: @soka sorry for late but can u share on what xml it's that error i must type where it's that